# Paypal payments redirecting to fraudulent URL

Tags: phishing, paypal

At my place of work, our paypal appeared to have been compromised so that a clone of paypal would appear and ask for customer credentials. The url it directed to was `https://checkoutnow.mdigo.com/store/login.php`, and searching this on google yields no real results, so I don't really know what to search for.

The slightly alarming thing is that none of this triggered any of our security systems and it was only when a customer notified us that we were able to disable paypal payments temporarily.

We are using Prestashop as the ecommerce platform. This is hosted on a server on which we own. There is a whitelist of IP addresses that may access our server and change site details.

I need help in researching this type of security breach so we can avoid it in the future. So, I ask:

- What is this type of URL obfuscation called?
- How could they have got past when only whitelisted IP's can access
  the server and change this information?

---

We have changed the passwords for the website and upon doing a test there, the actual paypal site is redirected to when making a payment with paypal.

If you can help me improve the question, or need any more information, please leave a comment below.

Comment: "How could they have got past without triggering any of the security software?" There are so many different considerations and so many different ways this could be done, so it cannot be answered without knowing a lot more about your environment. Also, "security software" is not 100% effective, probably nowhere close.

Comment: Without knowing much about your system this question is too broad. Though, I would definitely check **DNS**...

Comment: There are several explanations why this might be happening...have you not investigated the situation a little bit more technically, at least?

Comment: All you tell us is that you have a site and it was hacked. We can't begin to guess at the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question, although I will probably need to improve it a good bit more. I only work there part-time, as I'm still in college, and don't know all the specific details- and I'm also not entirely sure what I need to be asking for in order to diagnose the problem further. I can get all this information quite easily though, I just need to ask. Thank you!